# Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.Transform' to `UnityEngine.GameObject'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial for a 2D platformer and ran into this error that I have not been able to find a solution for yet. I'm new to code and GameDev.

I have tried changing the type under the variable declaration from Transform to GameObject which clears the compile error but then throws a new error within Unity "InvalidCastException.

Sorry if this is such a simple fix, this is all new to me.

```
public void _KillEnemy(Enemy _enemy)
    {

        GameObject _clone = Instantiate(_enemy.deathParticles, _enemy.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Destroy(_clone, 5f);
        cameraShake.Shake(_enemy.shakeAmt, _enemy.shakeLength);
        Destroy(_enemy.gameObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast a `Transform` to a `GameObject`. You need to call the property `gameObject` of `Transform`. See more: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html

```
    public void _KillEnemy(Enemy _enemy)
    {

        GameObject _clone = Instantiate(_enemy.deathParticles, _enemy.transform.position, Quaternion.identity).gameObject;
        Destroy(_clone, 5f);
        cameraShake.Shake(_enemy.shakeAmt, _enemy.shakeLength);
        Destroy(_enemy.gameObject);
    }
```